# Make query to update every document (insert field) which has field ratings.driver

Tags: mongodb

I want to add the field 'time':"2017-06-20 13:17:46" to every document that already have ratings.driver

Something like this

```
db.getCollection('dectar_rides').update({'ratings.driver': {$exists: true , $set:'ratings.driver.time':'2017-06-20 13:17:46' }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things, use [`updateMany`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) to update multiple documents. Any `update` function requires two parameters

```
db.getCollection('dectar_rides').updateMany(
  {'ratings.driver': {$exists: true}} , 
  {$set:{'ratings.driver.time':'2017-06-20 13:17:46' }}
);
```

PS: You need to first learn JSON syntax, so that you will be able to write valid queries